# Is difference amplifier a differential amplifier with a voltage gain of one?

Tags: differential

I see these two terms are used in same context.
But what is the difference in meaning?
Is difference amplifier a subset of differential ampfier with unity gain? I couldnt find a duplicate question.

Comment: Can you show us a context?

Comment: They have exactly the same topology

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/opampvar6.html#c2 vs https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html

Comment: in my experience, the terms are inter-changeable. Tho on silicon, the term diff-pair refers to that first set of transistors; originally just 2 matched devices, then thermal-transient-cancellation and miller-cascading and bias-current cancellation have arrived to greatly complicate that simple 2-device differential-pair schematic.

Answer (score 1):

> **There is " no difference " between the terms "Difference Amplifier" and "Differential Amplifier"   (pun intended)**

They both amplify the difference between 2 nodes, whether you have a signal on both or just one and connect the other one to some DC reference voltage.

Then the impedance ratio is 50% going into the non-inverting side with a gain of 1/2*2=1, it is unity gain while the inverting side has the same divider ratio with a gain of -1 then it is a "unity-gain differential (or difference) amplifier" which is a special case of any "diff amp".( slang description = diffy)

**Other info;**

The gain and frequency shape can be varied as long as the ratios are matched. So instead of simply Rf/Rin=gain it can be any combination of RLC parts matched on both sides.

Matching is the hard part for discrete parts (0.1% error on 4 parts < 55 dB CMRR while integrated INstrument Amps (INA) offer  CMRR > 110 dB needing only 1 R shared to control gain instead of matching 4 parts or 2 ratios, using laser trimmed internal R's.